# Nim game not working Java

Tags: java, methods, boolean

It works except it just does the computer move once and then loops the player move until it ends. Another issue is I tried (with boolean methods) to make it so it's impossible to take, for example 3 stones if there are only 2 left, that also seems to not be working... I'm new to java, please help

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NimGame
{
    public static int computerMoves(int stones)
    {
        int computer = (int)(Math.random()*3)+1;
        return computer;
    }

    public static boolean checkIfComputerValid(int stones)
    {
        int computer = computerMoves(stones);

        if (computer < stones)
        {
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }


    }

    public static boolean checkIfPlayerValid(int stones, int player)
    {

        if (player == 1 || player == 2 || player == 3)
        {
            return true;
        }

        else if (player > stones)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }


    }

    public static void gamePlay()
    {

        int stones = 25, computer, player;
        boolean valc, valp;
        Scanner inData = new Scanner (System.in);
        computer = computerMoves(stones);
        valc = checkIfComputerValid(stones);

        while(valc == false)
        {
           computer = computerMoves(stones);
           valc = checkIfComputerValid(stones);    
        }
        while(valc == true)
        {
            System.out.println("The computer takes "+computer+ " stone(s)");
            stones = stones - computer;
            System.out.println("There are "+stones+" stones remaining.");
            valc = checkIfComputerValid(stones);  

            if(stones == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("The computer wins.");
                return;
            }

            System.out.println("How many stones will you take?(max 3): ");
            player = inData.nextInt();
            valp = checkIfPlayerValid(stones, player);

            while(valp == false)
            {
                System.out.println(player +" stones is invalid, choose to take 1, 2, or 3.");
                player = inData.nextInt();
                valp = checkIfPlayerValid(stones, player);
            }

            while(valp == true && stones > 0)
            {
                stones = stones - player;
                System.out.println("There are "+stones+" stones remaining.");
                valp = checkIfPlayerValid(stones, player);

                if (stones == 0)
                {
                        System.out.println("You win.");
                        return;
                }

            }
          } 

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
           gamePlay();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the rules of the game you're trying to build here (and what exactly you're asking) but one thing that jumps into the eyes- your entire first method can be replaced with `return computerMoves(stones) < stones;` and the entire second method with `return player == 1 || player == 2 || player == 3;`. writing `if (something) {return true;} else{ return false;}` is redundant, just use `return something;`

Comment: and he can replace all conditions if(something == ture) with if(something) and if(something == false) with if(!something)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the game is simple. You need to organize your code such that you keep track of how many stones are remaining hence, you need a top-level while loop that keeps looping as long as `stones > 0` and then next thing you need is a variable to keep track of whether it is computer's turn to play or player's turn to play so, a boolean `playerTurn` with initial value of false.

Basically when `while (stones > 0)` begin its first loop, the following takes place:

- if playerTurn is checked which returns false in first loop because computer takes the first turn
- else condition is executed it
- Computer picks stones
- Stones are validated
- Set playerTurn = true, so player play next
- The if condition checks if `stones == 0` if yes, then computer is the winner and the execute `continue;` statement which takes the control to `while (stones > 0)`
- if stones != 0 then control is returned to while stones > 0, loop check yes
- If condition checks if player turn, yes then it allows player to provide no of stones
- Once inside playerTurn if condition, set playerTurn false so computer play next
- validate the number of stones
- substract the number of stones
- check if stones == 0 then player is the winner and take control back to while (stones > 0) else exit the if condition and control goes back to while (stones > 0)

The above process continues until the condition if(stones == 0) is satisfied inside the if (playerTurn) or else block which decides who is the winner.

You had so many loops, you need to replace some loops with if conditions. I have modified your gamePlay method, please see below (just gamePlay method):

```
public static void gamePlay()
    {
        int stones = 25, computer, player;
        boolean valc, valp;
        Scanner inData = new Scanner (System.in);
        computer = computerMoves(stones);
        valc = checkIfComputerValid(stones);

        //keep track of player and compute rturn 
        boolean playerTurn = false; 

        //terminates when no more stones are left
        while(stones > 0) {

            //player if block
            if(playerTurn) {
                //set playerTurn to false so next time computer play
                playerTurn = false; 
                System.out.println("How many stones will you take?(max 3): ");
                player = inData.nextInt();
                valp = checkIfPlayerValid(stones, player);

                //invalid input by player, keep asking him for valid input, not need to say valp == false, !valp will do
                while(!valp)
                {
                    System.out.println(player +" stones is invalid, choose to take 1, 2, or 3.");

                    player = inData.nextInt();
                    valp = checkIfPlayerValid(stones, player);
                }

                //if condition not while loop, no need to say valp == true, valp will do
                if(valp) {
                    stones = stones - player;
                    System.out.println("There are "+stones+" stones remaining.");
                    valp = checkIfPlayerValid(stones, player);

                    //if stones == 0 then player is the winner, 
                    if (stones == 0)
                    {
                            System.out.println("You win.");

                            //take control to top-level while loop which terminates to while (stones > 0) == false, game end.
                            continue;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                //just in case 
                valc = false; 
                while(!valc)
                {
                   computer = computerMoves(stones);
                   valc = checkIfComputerValid(stones);    
                }

                if(valc) {
                    System.out.println("The computer takes "+computer+ " stone(s)");
                    stones = stones - computer;
                    System.out.println("There are "+stones+" stones remaining.");

                    //set player turn so player play next
                    playerTurn = true; 

                    //computer wins
                    if(stones == 0) {
                        System.out.println("The computer takes "+computer+ " stone(s)");

                        //take control to while (stones > 0) which will become false and loop terminate, game end.
                        continue; 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is sample output:

```
The computer takes 2 stone(s)
There are 23 stones remaining.
How many stones will you take?(max 3): 
2
There are 21 stones remaining.
The computer takes 3 stone(s)
There are 18 stones remaining.
How many stones will you take?(max 3): 
1
There are 17 stones remaining.
The computer takes 1 stone(s)
There are 16 stones remaining.
How many stones will you take?(max 3): 
3
There are 13 stones remaining.
The computer takes 3 stone(s)
There are 10 stones remaining.
How many stones will you take?(max 3): 
2
There are 8 stones remaining.
The computer takes 1 stone(s)
There are 7 stones remaining.
How many stones will you take?(max 3): 
3
There are 4 stones remaining.
The computer takes 3 stone(s)
There are 1 stones remaining.
How many stones will you take?(max 3): 
1
There are 0 stones remaining.
You win.
```

Answer (score 0):

I took your main gamePlay method and interpreted its intention using pseudo-code. Here's how it reads to me:

```
    Computer chooses number of stones
    make sure computer picked a valid amount

    loop while computer picked a valid amount

        reduce remaining amount by computer's choice

        computer chooses

        check if the computer won
           return if it did

        ask player to choose, and validate input

        make sure player picked a valid amount

        loop on valid player input and stones remain

            reduce remaining amount by player's choice

            validate player input

             check if player won
               return if he did
```

By following the logic in the pseudo-code I see that once the player picks a valid number of stones the program reduces by that number of stones until it hits zero without letting either the computer or player pick again. I also notice unneeded calls to some of the methods. 
(The game does have a bug where the number of remaining stones can drop below zero but I'm not addressing that issue here).

When I think about how the game is played here is the pseudo-code I come up with:

```
 set computer as current player
 loop while there are stones remaining
    have current player pick stones, validate selection
    reduce remaining stones count
    check if someone won
      return if the game is over
    switch computer/player as current player
```

From that pseudo-code I came up with a gamePlay() implementation of

```
public static void gamePlay() {
    int stonesRemaining = 25;
    System.out.println("The game begins with " + stonesRemaining + " stones");

    boolean playersTurn = false;
    int stonesJustTaken = 0;
    while (stonesRemaining >= 0) {
        if (playersTurn) {
            stonesJustTaken = playerMoves(stonesRemaining);
        } else {
            stonesJustTaken = computerMoves(stonesRemaining);
            System.out.println("The computer takes " + stonesJustTaken + " stone(s)");
        }

        stonesRemaining = stonesRemaining - stonesJustTaken;
        System.out.println("There are " + stonesRemaining + " stones remaining.");

        if (stonesRemaining <= 0) {
            printWinningMessage(playersTurn);
            return;
        }
        playersTurn = !playersTurn;
    }
}
```

I use [intention-revealing names](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?IntentionRevealingNames) for the variables and methods in the hopes of expressing in the code what the comments try to explain. The length of the names aren't an issue since a good IDE will provide autocomplete and I don't have to type more than a few characters. I'm a firm believer in [writing code to be understood later](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/06/2036150.aspx), even on small applications like this.